# What is a "亲传弟子" and how would you say it in English?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 亲传弟子

I'm not sure how to say it words, but I believe that they are disciples that get things personally passed down by their master and they have a very close relationship with them. However, is there any specific word that can describe it in English?

EDIT: In terms of Chinese Wuxia novels.

Comment: Would you add some more information about the context? Martial arts, buddhism, something else? In Buddhism, it might be 'dharma heir' the word you are looking for, but I am not sure, what is your subject domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "Direct Disciple", I remember that's how people used to describe my Wushu Master.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked a few sources, in many cases it is just `disciple` without any adjective. `Personal disciple` is used in some cases, and sometimes `direct disciple`, like @leo4jc pointed out. `Immediate disciple` is another variant.

In my deleted answer, without knowing the context, I wrote 'dharma heir' (Buddhism), but that doesn't apply to wuxia, of course.